# Aries blueprint: custom namespace handlers

Tags: osgi, aries

I read that Aries allows to have own custom namespace handlers to support custom tags.
I cannot find any information or examples about the topic. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The class NamespaceHandler has a pretty good [javadoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.aries.blueprint/blueprint-parser/1.0.0/org/apache/aries/blueprint/NamespaceHandler.java). It is very similar to the [namespace handler API of Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html) so if you read about that Aries will be familiar. Also you can find examples in the aries subprojects: [jpa-blueprint-aries](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/jpa/jpa-blueprint-aries/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/jpa/blueprint/aries/impl/NSHandler.java) or [transaction-blueprint](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/transaction/transaction-blueprint/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/transaction/parsing/TxElementHandler.java)